# How to add a line break inbetween each lines in text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running a batch script to make a lines in text files with line breaks.
This is for a testing & learning purpose.

I have a text file named `file.txt` which contains,

```
this is line one
this is line two
this is line three
```

I am running the batch script with code,

```
type file.txt >> output.txt
echo >> output.txt
type file.txt >> output.txt
```

Expected `output.txt`,

```
this is line one

this is line two

this is line three
```

But, actual output am getting in `output.txt`,

```
this is line one
this is line two
this is line three
(Empty line here)
```

All I need is a line break inbetween each lines. Any help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: You should consider using a [tag:for-loop]: `@(For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Type "file.txt"')Do @Echo(%%A&Echo()>"output.txt"`. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?` to read its usage information.

Comment: Well, I can't believe the actual output you describe; with the code you've posted, the output file is going to contain the content of `file.txt` twice with something like `ECHO is on.` in between...

Answer (score 2):

The [redirection operator `>>`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) appends data to the redirection target (the file `output.txt` in your situation), but it cannot insert anything into them.

To accomplish your goal you need to read your input file `file.txt` line by line. This can be done by a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), like this:

```cmd
rem // Write to output file:
> "output.txt" (
    rem // Read input file line by line; empty lines and lines beginning with `;` are skipped:
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("file.txt") do @(
        rem // Return current line:
        echo(%%L
        rem // Return a line-break:
        echo/
    )
)
```

This appends another line-break and so an empty line at the end.
If you want to avoid that, you could use a variable, like this:

```cmd
rem // Reset flag variable:
set "FLAG="
rem // Write to output file:
> "output.txt" (
    rem // Read input file line by line; empty lines and lines beginning with `;` are skipped:
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("file.txt") do @(
        rem // Do not return line-break before first line:
        if defined FLAG echo/
        rem // Return current line:
        echo(%%L
        rem // Set flag variable to precede every following line by a line-break:
        set "FLAG=#"
    )
)
```